# Where is a certain file installed on Linux Mint?

Tags: linux-mint

I have just download Deluge bittorrent client. Not sure where installation files are in my system. I have to set this s/w as my default bittorent client, while selecting to open torrent file with which application it asks me to browse to that application file but I am not able to find the Deluge application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run Deluge using `deluge`, if you want to know where it is located is you can execute:

```
which deluge
```

This will tell you that `deluge` is in a location like `/usr/bin/deluge`